# React-native on 64-bit devices - debug works fine but not release. No problem with 32-bit devices at all

Tags: android, react-native, 64-bit, pouchdb

I googled a lot but none of findings is equal to my case:

1. Only 64-bit Android devices affected (tried on several - all the same)
2. Debug build on same devices attached via USB works with no issues
3. Release signed build hangs on every 64-bit device (tried both 64/32 versions)
4. 32-bit and universal signed release works like a charm on 32-bit devices

How it could be possible that SAME CODE works differently in debug and release, why? Different JS Core used?

[UPD]
catlog shows problem with pouchdb replication:

```
{ [Error]
10-19 08:55:39.157 22836 22855 I ReactNativeJS:   line: 132,
10-19 08:55:39.157 22836 22855 I ReactNativeJS:   column: 7285,
10-19 08:55:39.157 22836 22855 I ReactNativeJS:   sourceURL: 'index.android.bundle',
10-19 08:55:39.157 22836 22855 I ReactNativeJS:   result: 
10-19 08:55:39.157 22836 22855 I ReactNativeJS:    { ok: false,
10-19 08:55:39.157 22836 22855 I ReactNativeJS:      start_time: '2019-10-19T05:55:38.997Z',
10-19 08:55:39.157 22836 22855 I ReactNativeJS:      docs_read: 0,
10-19 08:55:39.157 22836 22855 I ReactNativeJS:      docs_written: 0,
10-19 08:55:39.157 22836 22855 I ReactNativeJS:      doc_write_failures: 0,
10-19 08:55:39.157 22836 22855 I ReactNativeJS:      errors: [],
10-19 08:55:39.157 22836 22855 I ReactNativeJS:      status: 'aborting',
10-19 08:55:39.157 22836 22855 I ReactNativeJS:      end_time: '2019-10-19T05:55:39.155Z',
10-19 08:55:39.157 22836 22855 I ReactNativeJS:      last_seq: 0 } }
```

Which works fine in debug on same device.
How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that in debug build non-https requests are allowed by default, in production you *have to* specify exceptions otherwise code just dies silently, quite unclear Android approach. In iOS BTW there are similar issues. So nothing to do with Couch/Pouch DB, just OS specific network  mess

Answer (score 1):

Can you attach the logs from logcat? That would give a clue as to what is happening.

Install the release build on your device.

```
adb logcat -c // Clear all previous logs
adb logcat > log.txt // Dump logs to a separate file
```

Once you have the logs, please see if there are any exceptions from your package. If so share it over here and we can see whats going wrong. Without a log, it would be very difficult to speculate.